# jQuery.HTML not obeying formatting within text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why dose the following not obey formatting, the "li"s have no effect

```
<script>
function showENQ() {
jQuery('#enqtext').html("<li>showtext</li>");
}
$('#enq').live('pageshow', function () { showENQ();  });
</script>


<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search     Enquirylist..."
data-theme="e" data-filter-theme="d" >

<div id="enqtext"></div>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
jQuery('#enqtext').html("<li>showtext</li>");
```

to:

```
$('#enqtext').append("<li>showtext</li>");
```

Edit : Come to think of it, I would remove the Div of ID `#engtext` completely and give the ID `#engtext`  to your ul.

Comment: I do give the id on the UL the fillter works then but not the <li>s

Answer (score 0):

try `innerHTML` instead:

```
jQuery('#enqtext').html("<li>showtext</li>");
```

or

```
 jQuery('#enqtext').append("<li>showtext</li>");
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by obey? Does it put `showtext` without `li` tags?

Comment: If it is putting `<li>showtext</li>` all together without proper indentation then most probably you have some styles set for `li`?

Comment: What I mean is it just ignors <li>s it is if they were not there. What I am doing is creating a list and what it to be formated as per the jQuery nice layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but my first idea is that you are placing the `<li>`'s into a div and not directly into the list itself.

Might work if you append to the `ul` by giving it an id, e.g.

```
 <ul id="list" ... >
```

and then do

```
function showENQ() {
    jQuery('#list').append("<li>showtext</li>");
}
```

Also might be worth changing `enqtext` to a span instead of a div and finally, check that you are not changing the style of the list items, i.e. make sure you are not doing `list-style:none;` anywhere in your css.